# Can I compile any high level language for use with eeprom?

Tags: high-level, eeprom

I need to know if it is possible to compile any high level programming language for use with an eeprom. I know it is possible to strip a header from a compiled binary, but I am unsure how addresses will be effected.

Please do not mark this as "not a question." I get a lot of guff on this site from people who can't tell the difference between a stupid question, and something which is not a question.

**Can I compile any high level language for use with eeprom?**

(EDIT) I have a *Winbond 27C512 EEPROM* in my sights.

Comment: In theory, probably yes. From a practical viewpoint, however, the answer is often likely to be no (i.e., even though the language could be compiled to ROMable code, no compiler exists that's designed to do so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a C compiler for the processor in question, then there's no reason why you couldn't compile C code so that it could be placed in EEPROM (though, as is usual with embedded programming, you cannot use any of the libc functions, so you will have to implement a lot of it yourself). C also interoperates well with assembly code, so you can write your bootstrap routines in assembly before transitioning over to higher-level code written in C.

A typical C linker (e.g. GNU ldd) can be scripted so that it generates addresses compatible with your EEPROM; this is a common requirement for embedded development and other "bare-metal" applications. You can use `objcopy` to format the compiled binary in several different formats. With the GNU toolchain, you can probably also pull this off with a restricted subset of C++.

You are not likely to be able to do this with a lot of other popular high-level languages, though, because few languages have the sort of support for low-level constructs (such as direct pointer addressing) required for embedded development.